# Get command line flags of launched Puppeteer instance programmatically

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I'm launching a Puppeteer instance that I would like to get some info of which flags this instance was launched with. For example, the `--user-data-dir` flag since sometimes I would like to use the same Puppeteer profile that would store cookies and login info.

Is there a way to fetch the values visible at `chrome://version` programmatically?

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
const browserURL = 'http://127.0.0.1:9222';
browser = await puppeteer.connect({browserURL,defaultViewport : null });
page = await browser.newPage();
})();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```js
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch();
  console.log(browser.process().spawnargs);
  await browser.close();
})();
```

UPD. For connected browser:

```js
  await page.goto('chrome://version');
  const tableCell = await page.waitForSelector('#command_line');
  const commandLine = await page.evaluate(element => element.innerText, tableCell);
  console.log(commandLine);
```

Comment: thank you for you're answer , it works only if it's puppeteer launch , mine is connection to a chrome instance . sorry for the unclarity

Comment: @DUMBUSER I've added another variant.

Answer (score 0):

Puppeteer has [browser.version()](http://browser.version()) function which return the same information.

```
let details = browser.version()
```

or

```
let details = page.browser.version()
```

You can check more information here : https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/api.md#browserversion

Comment: hi, so this return the version of browser , i need the flags that a browser was launched with that can be get from chrome://version